# Error while installing docker in wndows 10

Tags: docker

I didn't known why i am always getting this error while starting docker in my laptop windows 10.Bellow i have attached the pic which sows you the errors

[image]

Comment: You shouldn't post images of error messages, copy and paste them into the question body instead.

Comment: Did you try restarting it? Did you try reinstalling it? If yes, please post your exact version for Docker and as mentioned by @Haem cope-paste the entire output into code blocks, surround them with these quotes, omit the brackets: (```)